# The Minkowski $(N-1)$- dimensional upper constant of a closed curve?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded smooth boundary. Let $S\subset \Omega$ be a $N-1$ rectifiable set with $\mathcal H^{N-1}(S)<+\infty$. It is well know that if $S$ is not closed, then the Minkowski $(N-1)$- dimensional upper constant of $S$ could be infinite, i.e., 
$$
 \limsup_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}|\{x\in\Omega:\,\operatorname{dist}(x,S)<\epsilon\}|=+\infty
$$
For instance, we can take $S$ such that $\mathcal H^{N-1}(S)<+\infty$ but $\bar S=\Omega$ (the closure of $S$).

My question. Instead let $S$ be open, if I assume that $S$ is closed. That is, $S=\bar S$ and $H^{N-1}(\bar S)<+\infty$. Then, do I have 
$$
 \limsup_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{2\epsilon}|\{x\in\Omega:\,\operatorname{dist}(x,\bar S)<\epsilon\}|\leq \mathcal H^{N-1}(\bar S)
$$
hold?

---

It looks to me that Theorem $3.2.39$ in H. Federer's *Geometric measure theory* gives me exactly what I need... Can anybody confirm it for me? Thank you!

Comment: How could $S$ be open and have finite $\mathcal{H}^{N-1}$ measure? Surely, $\mathcal{H}^N (S) = \mathcal{L}^N (S) > 0$ in which case, $\mathcal{H}^{N-1} (S) = \infty$. Am I misunderstanding what you mean by open?

Comment: @PaulBryan  Maybe I should delete `open` but just state `not closed`. Sorry!